# New /24 IPs location is not correct

Tags: location, ip

We got new IP range /24 from a ripe member and their country is different from us.How can I correct this.
Many of our customers need to use IPs based on country list and sometimes we will get problem because this IPs is not show anywhere current country. In ripe we have mnt by our maintainer.

Comment: I'm not sure which StackExchange site this belongs on but it's definitely not on a programming help one

Answer (score 0):

As I find its not easy. but we can contact to RIPE Geo location service providers:

https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/db/tools/geolocation-in-the-ripe-database
should send email to this service providers and tell your AS number with IP range + new location they will check and trace. after 10 days to 1 Mnts your location will be update.